# Passing IPC(Instructions/Cycles) continuously to other function or variable

Tags: linux, performance, shell, linux-kernel, performancecounter

I am trying to read the performance counters and get the IPC. I need to use IPC to control few machine specific parameters. I am using shell script to do the same. Please see the code below:

```
while true
do 
    retval=./perf periodic -e instructions -e cycles -s 50 -d -m td &
    some_pid=$!
    kill some_pid
    if ["$retval" -gt "0.5"] 
        then
            ***something***
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

I am getting following error:

```
Algorithm.sh[27]: kill: some_pid: arguments must be jobs or process IDs
Algorithm.sh[27]: periodic: not found
Algorithm.sh[27]: [: missing ]
Algorithm.sh[27]: kill: some_pid: arguments must be jobs or process IDs
Algorithm.sh[27]: [: missing ]
Algorithm.sh[27]: periodic: not found
Algorithm.sh[27]: kill: some_pid: arguments must be jobs or process IDs
Algorithm.sh[27]: [: missing ]
```

Can someone give me some pointers on how to get/return the value from perf instruction. I tried using function and returning the value, but it also failed.

---------**UPDATED**----------

Now I am running following, and one of the problem got solved and one is remaining.

```
./perf periodic -e instructions -e cycles -s 50 -d -m td > result.txt &
```

And other one is

```
while true
do 
    retval=$(tail -n 1 result.txt)
    echo $retval
    if ["$retval" -gt "0.5"] 
        then
            echo "Hello mate"
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

The echo is giving value, but then the if statement is not getting executed. It is giving following:

```
Algorithm.sh[30]: [: missing ]
0.302430
Algorithm.sh[30]: [0.302430: not found
0.472716
Algorithm.sh[30]: [0.472716: not found
0.475687
Algorithm.sh[30]: [0.475687: not found
```

I looked up the if condition syntax and couldn't spot the mistake. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of shell syntax issues here.

First, `retval=...` is going to set the `retval` variable equal to the first part of the string on the right side of the '='. The ampersand will then background the whole thing, essentially throwing that value away. You probably meant to do:

```
retval=`./perf periodic -e instructions -e cycles -s 50 -d -m td`
```

which would store the output of the `perf` command into `retval`. However, that won't work if you put it into the background with '&'. You'll need to either (a) run it synchronously without the '&' as I've shown above, (b) redirect its output into a file and recover it after it's finished (you'll need to use `wait` to determine when that's happened), or (c) use a "coprocess" (too complicated to explain here: see the bash man page).

Also, you probably meant `kill $some_pid`? Without the '$', the string `"some_pid"` is passed as a literal argument to `kill`, which is probably not what you intended.

**Edit**

Following your revisions... The shell operates by splitting the command line up into individual tokens. So spaces are often important. In this case, the initial token being identified by the shell will be the combined value of `["$retval"` (after variable substitution and quote removal). The last token will be `0.5]` after removal of quotes. In the first invocation line then, the first token was simply '[' (presumably `retval` was empty the first time through). So there it's complaining about the last token not being the matching ']'. In the other iterations, the first token is '[' plus additional numeric text from `$retval` which is not providing a valid command name.

Once you fix that, you'll discover that the `-gt` operator only evaluates integer comparisons. You could use the `bc(1)` command. For example, this command will produce output of `1` if `$retval` is greater than 0.5; otherwise `0`.

```
echo "$retval > 0.5" | bc
```

But note you'll need to ensure `retval` has a valid numeric expression or you'll cause a syntax error in `bc`. You would then need to capture the output and put it into a conditional. Something like this should work:

```
if [ "$retval" ]
then
    x=$(echo "$retval > 0.5" | bc)
    if [ $x -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "hello mate"
    fi
fi
```

(Note that with `$(...)` you *don't* need additional spaces next to the parentheses. And in the assignment statement `x=foo`, you must *not* have a space on either side of the `=`.)

Comment: I updated the question with modifications mentioned by you. And now I am having problem in "if" statement.